# Combine DAO and Entity in Spring and Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, dao

I was wondering if it is possible to combine DAO and Entity in a single class. e.g.

#### In rails

If I have table named `user` then there will be one ActiveRecord User and by using that class I can access access Methods related to DB and user i.e. it has both methods `user.name` (accessing object properties) and `user.save` / `User.get_all` methods (managing DB interactions) in the same class

#### In Spring/Hibernate Configuration

I have two things: DAO and Entity

**Entity:** I have User class that is an entity and is mapping Table as POJO, so that I can access methods related to a single user e.g. `user.getName()`

**DAO:** I have a DAO in which there are DB interactions e.g. `userDAO.save(user)` and `userDAO.get(id)`.

#### Question:

I was wondering if I can create single User class and define User properties and getter/setter inside along with DB interactions so that I can single class as both, i.e. `user.getName()` (as POJO) and `User.get(id)`/`user.save()` (as DAO).

Is this method possible, and why are the complications I might run into, if I start with this approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's called Active Record Pattern . Here is article about topic for JPA . [Active Record Pattern](https://www.infoq.com/articles/ActiveJPA) . and example https://github.com/ActiveJpa/activejpa

> Is this method possible, and why are the complications I might run into, if I start with this approach?

it's :

1. [Cohesion & Coupling](https://sanaulla.info/2008/06/26/cohesion-and-coupling-two-oo-design-principles/)
2. if it's real project , it might become problem to support it
3. when you have 20 entities it's difficult to decide where to put method into what entity , and also find method that you need as it might be in many places
4. when you don't use active record pattern you can share entity with web layer , with active record entity can't be Serializable.
5. code become bigger and bigger